# React, error importing file from root folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error (`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '.../action/cartActions'`) occurs at the `cartDetails`.js file.

I am attaching the file structure screenshot below,

[image]

Import statement =     `import cartAction from '.../action/cartActions';`

The following action's are getting uploaded from cartActions `export default {add,remove,increment,decrement,removeall}`

As answers suggested,I tried removing one dot from import but hit with same error

[image]

Comment: two dots... not three

Comment: Even with two dots, same error happens

Comment: `../../action/cartActions`

Comment: @ James,Kudos..

Answer (score 2):

You typed one dot too much, should be `../action/cartActions`

Comment: That's not worth an answer... a comment would suffice... Provides 0 value for future users... It's just a typo...

Comment: Then removing the question alltogether is the way to go...

Comment: It's difficult to remove questions when they have answers... That's the entire point...

Comment: Oh, now I get it, sorry :) Still quite new to stackoverflow...